# Using MATLAB, any suggestion on how I can get rid of the white squares in the image?

Tags: matlab, extract

I am trying to extract the white blobs (non-square) in this image:

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to Image Processing Toolbox? If so, this example code may be helpful: http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/demos.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexcell.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sobel` or `canny` to remove the squares of the image, or you can use one threshold to find Connected Objects. For this use the [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwlabel.html) function; one example is found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22766-number-plate-segmentation-of-a-car/content/seg.m).